# Select rows where column values are latest unique

Tags: sql, sqlite

Please, help to find appropriate query.

**Task**: table contains sms. Select latest sms from each conversation

**Table example**:

[image]

**Query result**

[image]

Thanks a lot in advance

Comment: Adjust the sample data, have some date values in other order than id.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is the solution to your problem:

```
SELECT MAX(id) AS ID, conversationId, Max(date) AS Date 
FROM Table_name 
GROUP BY conversationId
```

Answer (score 1):

Use *subquery* with correlation

```
select * 
from table t
where date = (select max(date) from table where conversationid = t.conversationid)
```